# Python return to fetch JS function

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch

I have a JS calling a Python function. Here is the JS call :

```
fetch('/ws/invoice/checkDoublon', {
    method  : 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body    : JSON.stringify({
        'invoiceNumber' : invoiceNumber.val(),
        'vatNumber'     : vatNumber.val(),
        'id'            : $('#pdfId').val()
    })
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

My Python code is like this (i'm using Flask) :

```
@bp.route('/ws/invoice/checkDoublon',  methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def checkInvoiceDoublon():
if request.method == 'POST':
    data            = request.get_json()
    invoiceNumber   = data['invoiceNumber']
    vatNumber       = data['vatNumber']
    invoiceId       = data['id']

    _vars   = init()
    _db     = _vars[0]
    _cfg    = _vars[1].cfg

    # Check if there is already an invoice with the same vat_number and invoice number. If so, verify the rowid to avoid detection of the facture currently processing
    res = _db.select({
        'select'    : ['rowid, count(*) as nbInvoice'],
        'table'     : ['invoices'],
        'where'     : ['supplier_VAT = ?', 'invoiceNumber = ?'],
        'data'      : [vatNumber, invoiceNumber]
    })[0]

    if res['nbInvoice'] == 1 and res['rowid'] != invoiceId or res['nbInvoice'] > 1 :
         return 'Duplicate', 200
    else:
         return 'Not duplicate', 200
```

All of this works but the  `console.log(response)` doesn't show at all the custom return I want from Python "Not duplicate" or "Duplicate". It only show OK as response.statusText because I return the HTTP code 200

How could I retrieve a custom message on my JS code ? It could be great if it's using fetch and not ajax

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

this is because [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) return a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) on which you need to call either [`.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) or [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) the two returning a `Promise` containing your data as an object or a string depending on the one you've chosen

your js would look something like this

```js
fetch('/ws/invoice/checkDoublon', {
    method  : 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body : JSON.stringify({
        'invoiceNumber' : invoiceNumber.val(),
        'vatNumber'     : vatNumber.val(),
        'id'            : $('#pdfId').val()
    })
  }).then(function(response) {
    response.json().then(function(data) {
      // here data is the object containing your datas
    })
    // or
    response.text().then(function(value) {
      // here value is the string returned by your python script
      let data = JSON.parse(value) // this line transform the string into the same object you get by calling .json() above
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a valid JSON Response from your Flask backend

Answer (score -1):

You can take it in a promise pipe line and extract all data :
[image: 1]

The python server for my code is this

[image]
[image]
[image]